# I am trying to understand CORS but why does the server send the allow access option?

Tags: cors

I read this on the MDN site:

> Let us look at what the browser will send the server in this case,
> and let's see how the server responds:

```
GET /resources/public-data/ HTTP/1.1
Host: bar.other
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.1b3pre) Gecko/20081130 Minefield/3.1b3pre
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://foo.example/examples/access-control/simpleXSInvocation.html
Origin: http://foo.example


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 01 Dec 2008 00:23:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.61 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/xml

[XML Data]
```

> Lines 1 - 10 are headers sent by Firefox 3.5.  Note that the main
> HTTP request header of note here is the Origin: header on line 10
> above, which shows that the invocation is coming from content on the
> domain http://foo.example.

Why is the server sending this line:

> Acesss-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>
> In this case, the server responds with a Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
>
> - which means that the resource can be accessed by any domain in a cross-site manner.

But does the browser then read this line and not allow resources to pass unless cross-site requests were allowed? Why is it structured this way? Shouldn't the server be doing the restricting and not the browser receiving this line?

Answer (score 1):

**[CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) *relaxes restrictions* on the [Same-Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) *already* built in browsers; CORS does *not* add any security!**

> Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that *allows restricted resources* .. requested from another domain outside the domain from which the resource originated.

This is needed to counter the Same-Origin Policy which is a *restriction enforced by browsers*; it mitigates hijacking sessions, prevents unwanted cross-domain POST requests, and prohibits leaking data between domains in a way that can be accessed via XSS, etc.

> .. [under Same-Origin Policy], a *web browser* permits scripts contained in a first web page to access data in a second web page, but *only* if both web pages have the same origin.

Since this restriction is *imposed* by the browser it must be *removed* by browser which is exactly what the Access-Control-* headers do: the server informs the browser the resource can be requested/accessed, even when it would otherwise violate the Same-Origin Policy.

The server 'protects' itself against CORS-related changes by *not* allowing CORS. In this manner CORS, and the *relaxing* for Same-Origin Policy, is an *opt-in controlled by the remote server*.

Server security (and correct handling of user-supplied data, non-idempotent actions, sessions, etc) is a separate topic as requests might come from the same domain or be created outside of a browser; such security is thus separate from CORS/Same-Origin concerns.

Comment: But what's interesting is that I built an API with Rails and I can already see the JSON response using my browser, but I cannot see consume the api via another front-end framework. If I visit the endpoint with chrome it works without any CORS implementation in my server... why is this?

Comment: @Jwan622 SOP (and thus CORS) affects the ability of client code/operations to 'access' returned data directly; it does not [necessarily] affect the ability of browser tools to view the response. Since SOP *is* applied *in browsers* (usually even when embedded) this is the only 'response' I can give to such a query - that has naught to do with the original question - given a vague description and no SSCCE.